# How to consolidate split transactions in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
Col1      Col2     Col3
A         10       20
A         20       30
A         30       40
A         50       60
```

I want an output such as this:

```
 Col1      Col2     Col3
    A         10      40
    A         50      60
```

thereby eliminating multiple transaction times for a single transaction.

I am looking for a solution without involving date functions.

Thank You

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: There are a number of question here already about merging date ranges (which is the same logic) or merging intervals in SQL if you want to search, but at first glance I can't see which is the best.